# Windows doesnt recognize my hdd

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

I have one 250 GB SSD, one 1500 GB, and the last one is 4000 GB.

But last time the cables get unplugged. I fixed today and only say `Disco 1` is a 128 GB disk instead. BIOS also detect the disk but see 128 GB too.

[image]

**Test Disk result:**

[image]

What can I do? Or is the HDD broken?

Comment: I assume Windows is asking for you to initialize the disk (I can't tell because your image isn't in English as required) but it means your partition table is corrupt.  Tools like TestDisk can help repair the corruption in some cases

Comment: @Ramhound Well I cant change my windows lenguaje what part you need translate? Test disk say the problem is somewhere else.